# R, GGPlot2 & geom_pointrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some sample data for which I'm trying to turn into a line-like graph.

```
sample <- data.frame(inst=c('School1', 'School1', 'School1', 'School1', 'School2', 'School2', 'School2', 'School2', 'School3', 'School3', 'School3', 'School3'), variable=c('Math_25', 'Math_75', 'Reading_25', 'Reading_75', 'Math_25', 'Math_75', 'Reading_25', 'Reading_75', 'Math_25', 'Math_75', 'Reading_25', 'Reading_75'), peer_min=c(50, 84, 61, 83, 40, 60, 55, 85, 52, 75, 75, 87), peer_max=c(66, 95, 77, 90, 55, 85, 72, 91, 67, 83, 84, 95), peer_mean=c(58.0, 89.5, 69.0, 86.5, 47.5, 72.5, 63.5, 88.0, 59.5, 79.0, 79.5, 91.0), inst_value=c(55, 93, 65, 95, 60, 70, 65, 80, 60, 85, 77, 89))
```

and from that sample data, I constructed this graph

```
e <- ggplot(sample, aes(x=inst, y=peer_mean, ymin = peer_min, ymax = peer_max, color=variable)) + geom_pointrange() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

The question I have is, how can I add `sample$inst_value` as a different dot on these lines?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another layer with `geom_point()` and its own aesthetics:

```
sample %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=inst, y=peer_mean, ymin = peer_min, ymax = peer_max, color=variable)) + 
  geom_pointrange() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = inst, y = inst_value)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Comment: we don't even need to redefine `aes(x=...) ` since its the same and will inherit from `ggplot()`, just change the vars that need to change

Comment: Thank you! I've tried many variations of this and I think I was getting the order wrong. Thank you for your help.